# SQL Server 2008 sysobjects location

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just started to query dbo.sysobjects for more experience in Sql Server.My question is where is located physically on sql server, because I look into System Databases -> master, model, msdb -> Tables -> System Tables and nothing found.

Comment: Well, for one, you should be using sys.objects, not sysobjects. sysobjects is a deprecated, backward-compatibility view - so you will find it under Views -> System Views -> sys.sysobjects (not dbo.sysobjects).

Comment: It'd be in your database > Views > System Views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are *views* that reflect information about the structure and state of the server and its contained objects.

While they operate like user defined views, they could be implemented directly by the SQL Server code without any structures in any database.

That tools show them just indicates how much they look like user defined views, not that they exist in a database (system or user).